# Best practices for using slam toolbox without odometry

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to try out the slam toolbox, however, but as the hardware of the robot is currently developed, I only have a laser on a movable platform, but so far no source of odometry. We want to test the toolbox in a new environment that we can't visit too often, so I have to live with laser only for some time.

How should I configure the toolbox? Is there a way to deactivate odometry?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356514/best-practices-for-using-slam-toolbox-without-odometry/) by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3519 on 2020-07-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose_B](https://answers.ros.org/users/59709/jose_b/) on 2020-10-16**:
Hi NEngelhard, could you find the way to test slam toolbox with the scan matcher how did you do it? Could you show me some example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must provide odometry for all methods of SLAM in ROS except Cartographer (in which you still should, the non-odometry version isn't great). Therefore, you should find some suitable alternative using some laser odometry methods or test in simulation where you can provide simulated odometry.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2020-07-20**:
I used a scan matcher as odometry source. [BTW: hector_slam also works without odometry]

**Comment by [androadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/34219/androadi/) on 2022-02-03**:
Hi @NEngelhard, did you get slam_toolbox working with laser_scan_matcher?